# Passing data one form to another that was already opened and hidden

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, textbox

I have a Windows Forms Application that when you run it, the main form is the login. If you select "register", it hides the form, and opens another form where you put your data in order to register. Is there a way that, when registration is complete, and the registration form closes, when the login from shows up again it has automatically in the "username" textbox the value that you used in the previous form when you registered? I am not able to figure this out.

Comment: webforms or mvc or desktop app?

Comment: Sry, forgot to say it. Windows Form Application.

Comment: I think that you should change your approach concerning the form process, i.e. : 1) the first form shall be the real application form 2) when activated (Form.Activated event), create and show the login form (with ShowDialog) 3) refer to Tomtom response.for interactions with the registration form –

Comment: Thanks for the recomendation. I'm currently moving from PHP to C# and I'm still a little bit off track here.

Comment: @graffito I did what you've recommended there, but I have a problem. If you are not logged in (didn't click remember me) the form login shows perfectly without the main showing, but if you close the login form, first the main form shows up, and then the aplication terminates. I'm using Application.Exit(); but the main form still shows up even if I explicitly hide it. Is there something that I'm missing out? (thanks for the idea, still new to C# ^^)

Comment: When you need to login, hide the main form in Form.activated event, before the login form ShowDialog. When the ShowDialog returns, either show the main form if ok or Application.Exit().

Comment: @graffito I did that, but on the form load event. Is there a difference between them? Should it work if I do it on the activated event?

Comment: I changed to the activated event, but now it first shows the main form for like half a second before hiding it. On the bright side, it doesn't shows up when I close the login form. But form is not supposed to show before the login, it's supposed to be running hidden in background until you log in.

Comment: After the InitializeComponents of main form, set its WindowStyle property to minimized. Set it to Maximized or Normal, if no lgin or login succeeded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82300/discussion-between-user3153340-and-graffito).

Comment: Figured a way out of it. Running this.Hide() on the Form.Load event at the main form, create a dispose function in the form, and calling it from the Login.Close event. Main doesn't show up anymore before the login, neither after closing it.

Answer (score 0):

In your register-Window you can add a public/internal property which provides the Username. I guess you're calling the register-form something like:

```
private void ShowRegisterWindow(...)
{
   frmRegister register = new frmRegister();
   register.ShowDialog();      
}
```

This you can change to something like:

```
private void ShowRegisterWindow(...)
{
   frmRegister register = new frmRegister();
   DialogResult result = register.ShowDialog();      
   if(result == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      tbUsername.Text = register.Username;
   }
}
```

In your Register-Form after you saved the the user set the property for Username and set the DialogResult of this form to OK.

The property for the Username in your RegisterForm can also look like:

```
public string Username
{
   get { return tbUsername.Text; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try this as soon as I get back to home. I'll tell you how it went.

Comment: Okay, I tried... Didn't work. The register form is not "directly called" from the login form, it is called from a dinamically created menu strip on a totally different class file.

Also, I've implemented what @Graffito told me about making the common form as the main and show login dialog from there, but the procedure is something like this.

application runs - main form hides, login form shows - external class file check OS version, app version, regional configs and bla bla and creates a menustrip based on that - one option of menu strip is the register account wich creates the register form.